# Silverlight Domain Service - How to have a single [Invoke] operation

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I have a custom domain service with a single [Invoke] operation that returns a List of User objects.

In order to get it to compile, I have to stump out the User object in a property (highlighted as 'DONOTUSE' below) or method outside of the [Invoke] operation otherwise I am met with the following compile time error:

> Operation named 'GetUsers' does not conform to the required signature. Return types must be an entity or complex type, a collection of entities or complex types, or one of the predefined serializable types.

Once I stump out the property it compiles and executes as intended, but the hack annoys the heck out of me.

I do **not** wish to use the [Query] attribute so please do not suggest that I do.  I say this because if I do switch to [Query] it compiles fine, however, I do not want to deal with the EntityQuery result set or its deferred execution.

Due to the way I have the designed the architecture, the needs of the use case in this example and MSDN documentation, [Invoke] is the most appropriate means.

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class UserDomainService : DomainService
{

    private IUserService userService;
    public UserDomainService(IUserService service)
    {
        userService = service;
    }

    [Invoke, RequiresAuthentication]
    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return userService.GetUsers();
    }

    //HOW CAN I REMOVE THE FOLLOWING AND STILL COMPILE?
    public User DONOTUSE()
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I'll leave you with this...  I have another project that has custom DomainServices with single [Invoke] operations and *it* compiles fine.  I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why one would compile over the other.

**UPDATE**

See comments in the selected answer below.

Comment: Does your domain service that compiles return an entity datatype, or a simple datatype like string or List<string>?

Comment: Do you have a [Key] on your User object?  If not this may be the problem.  When RIA generates the client-side proxy it needs a field marked [Key] in order to uniquely identify instances.  Also, what is User a subclass of?  If it uses a namespace that is not supported by Silverlight that could also be a problem

Comment: @Noel: No it does not - very similar to the above except no service DI.  @Nissan Fan:  User is a POCO object and it does have a [Key] attribute on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried exposing users like this ?

```
IQueryable<User> GetUsers() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
```

That's a way of forcing the WCF Ria code generator to expose your entity client-side. You might try using shared code too, Class.shared.cs, look it up in the WCF Ria docs

Comment: Yes and that works...  However, it is similar to what I have done with the 'DONOTUSE' property above.  I want to be able to get away from that 'hack like' approach.

Comment: That's a way of forcing the WCF Ria code generator to expose your entity client-side. You might try using shared code too, Class.shared.cs, look it up in the WCF Ria docs.

Comment: @Maciek:  I was just about to answer my own question when I saw that you hit it right on the head...  The reason I was able to get it working in a different application was because I was sharing the library assembly.  Similarly, I could do as you mentioned, Class.shared.cs and that would work too.  If you wouldn't mind, please append this to the answer above. Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all. Glad I was able to help

Comment: @Maciek, is there a way to expose a non-entity type from RIA?

Comment: Yes, you can use a POCO (plain old clr). 1. create a class 2. mark one of the properties with a [Key] attribute (system.componentmodel.dataannotations) 3. Add a dummy Get method like in my original answer. 4. your class should now be usable both with [Query] and with [Invoke] methods